# Does a stoichiometric coefficient represent molecules or moles of a substance?

Tags: stoichiometry, mole

I understand that the one mole of atoms is equal to $6.02\times10^{23}$ atoms. However, when I used various resources to learn about stoichiometry, they showed me a balanced equation:

$$\ce{2H2O->2H2 + O2}$$

and said "2 moles of water" decomposed to form "2 moles of molecular hydrogen" and "1 mole of molecular oxygen". It is my understanding that there are only 2 molecules of water, not $2 \times 6.02 \times 10^{23}$ molecules of water and so on with the other parts of the equation as well. Could someone please clear up my confusion?

Answer (score 6):

Balanced equations represent ratios of reacting chemical species, not absolute quantities. What we mean when we say $$\ce{2H2 +O2->2H2O}$$ is not literally that two *molecules* of hydrogen react with one of oxygen, but rather that two *units* of hydrogen react. These units could be moles or molecules or something else entirely.

Comment: I'll just add that the units can't be weights or masses. The units ultimately have to be proportional to the number of molecules.

Answer (score 2):

The balanced equations are just ratios. Read your example closely, it states that:

> 2 **moles** of water decomposes to form 2 **moles** of hydrogen and 1 **mole** of oxygen.

Note that all of the units are in moles and the statement does NOT say:

> 2 **moles** of water decomposes to form 2 **molecules** of hydrogen and 1 **molecule** of oxygen.

The mole unit is just a multiplier.  The question could have alternatively said:

> 2000 **molecules** of water decomposes to form 2000 **molecules** of hydrogen and 1000 **molecules** of oxygen.

or

> $12.04\times10^{23}$ **molecules** of water decomposes to form $12.04\times10^{23}$ **molecules** of hydrogen and $6.02\times10^{23}$ **molecules** of oxygen.

and the implication of either would be the same. In all cases the ratio of water:hydrogen:oxygen is 2:2:1 respectively.